# Passing custom headers in a cross-domain ajax request with some older browsers

Tags: ajax, iis, http-headers, cors

Considering this following cross-domain request (replicable f.ex. in Safari 5.0.2, any OS):

**Request**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://myhost.tld/odata/Account(518059)', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJsb2phYWxpLXdlYmFwaS5jbG91ZGFwcC5uZXQiLCJleHAiOjEzOTQxMjM2MzcsImlzcyI6IldlYkFwaSIsImNhbXBJZCI6MjksInBvcnRhbElkIjozMiwidXNlcklkIjo1MTgwNTl9.c8223aYpb4X7kwYLSmSSQr4wGytxcYtOzTlQuHa9mYU');
xhr.send();
xhr.responseText;
```

**Response**

```
Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

**Headers**

```
OPTIONS /odata/Account(518059) HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.tld
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://myclient.tld
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Safari/533.18.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Authorization
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myclient.tld
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 16:37:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I verified that the web api correctly handles the request and indeed returns data with HTTP 200. However, the request seems to fail on some older browsers. So, I go ahead and hard code the Authorization token on the server side and leave it out from the equation and:

**Request**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://myhost.tld/odata/Account(518059)', false);
xhr.send();
xhr.responseText;
```

**Response**

```
{
    'odata.metadata': 'http://myhost.tld/odata/$metadata#Account/@Element',
    'Id': 518059,
    'userName': '643033849'
}
```

Voilà, it suddenly starts working. So, I download the whole internet to my hard drive and read it, but cannot find either a verification that f.ex. older Safaris don't support custom headers with cross-domain requests, neither I can find possible fix for the situation without going into the obvious Http Handler or JSONP route.

So, apart from the aforementioned 'fixes', is there anything I could do to securely transmit this token from my client to server thus avoiding the custom headers. OR, is there a way I could make them work?

**Cookies?**

Please don't suggest this. Some Safari versions, including 5.0.2, block cross-domain cookies unless the user has visited the target site of the cross-domain request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found no way actually fixing the situation. Like, some older versions of browsers simply don't support passing custom headers in CORS requests. And since we use Json Web Tokens in the authentication, I really need to have that.

So, I found about this `Application Request Routing (ARR)` module in `IIS` which uses `URL Rewrite` engine to create a `reverse proxy`. More specifically, mapping all the requests under `^/odata(.*)$` to my backend web api host.

**Here's the high level steps to configure a Reverse Proxy**

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Open site
3. In features view, choose URL Rewrite (provided that it's already installed)
4. Choose Add Rule(s)
5. In the Inbound and Outbound Rules, choose Reverse Proxy
6. If you don't have Application Request Routing (ARR) installed, it will prompt you to do just that, accept
7. Create rule to map a path to a backend server
8. Once saved, the rules will be written to the Web.config

   ```
   <rewrite>
     <rules>
       <rule name="ODataApiReverseProxy" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="^odata(.*)$" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="http://webapi.host.tld/{R:0}" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
     <outboundRules>
       <rule name="ODataRewriteJson" preCondition="ResponseIsJson" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
         <match filterByTags="None" pattern="webapi.host.tld" />
         <action type="Rewrite" value="client.host.tld" />
       </rule>
       <preConditions>
         <preCondition name="ResponseIsJson">
           <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^application/json" />
         </preCondition>
       </preConditions>
     </outboundRules>
   </rewrite>
   ```

Now, the client will completely skip the CORS preflight since it's connecting to the same host. Also, ARR allows much more in terms of configuration, caching, load balancing, monitoring and management etc.